# x86 assembly: program takes character as input returns binary format

Tags: assembly, x86

I have a C callable assembly program that I am executing but it is not outputting the correct answer. The program takes a `char` as input and then return the binary representation of that char. This is my program:

```
.globl _printbin
.text

_printbin:
    pushl  %ebp
    movl   %esp, %ebp
    xorl   %eax, %eax
    movl   8(%ebp), %ecx
    movl   $buffer, %edi  #move address of buffer to edi
    movl   %edi, %eax     #move edi to eax
    movl   $0x1, %ebx

loop:
    cmpb    $8, count     #compare count to 2
    je      end           #return if count == 2
    incb    count         #increment count

nibble:
    xorl %edx, %edx       #Clear out edx register
    movb %cl, %dl         
    and %bl, %dl          #And with powers of two to check for 1
    cmpb $0x0, %dl        
    jne changebit         # If dl reg is not zero change bit in buffer
    imul $0x2, %ebx
    jmp loop

changebit:
    movb $0x31, (%edi)
    incb %edi

end:
    movl   %esp, %ebp
    popl   %ebp
    ret

.data
buffer:
    .asciz "00000000"
count:
    .byte  0
.end
```

It is called like this inside the C program:

```
extern char *printbin(unsigned char);

int main(char **args)
{
  unsigned int x;

  printf("number to print in binary: \n");
  x = '+';
  printf("The binary format for %x is %s\n", 
                                 x,   printbin((unsigned char)x));
  return 0;
}
```

However, I am getting the output:

```
The binary format for 2b is 10000000
```

where I should be getting `0010 1011`.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Any particular reason you are type casting `(unsigned char)x` as your argument to `printbin` when `x` is an `int` and `printbin` reads it off the stack as an `int` anyway (which is the standard C calling convention)?

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of problems with your code:

- You don't increase `edi` if the current bit is a 0.
- If the current bit is a 1 you proceed to `end:` after storing the `'1'` instead of jumping back to `loop:`.
- You check the bits "right-to-left" (least significant bit first), but store the characters in the string left-to-right.

A working version could look like this:

```
_printbin:
    pushl  %ebp
    movl   %esp, %ebp
    movl   8(%ebp), %edx
    movl   $buffer, %edi  #move address of buffer to edi
    movl   %edi, %eax
    movl   $0x80, %ebx    # Mask
    movl   $8, %ecx       # Loop count

convert_byte:
    testb %bl, %dl        # Update EFLAGS based on dl AND bl
    jz no_change
    movb $'1',(%edi)
    no_change:
    inc %edi
    shrl %ebx             # ebx /= 2
    loop convert_byte     # ecx--; if ecx GOTO convert_byte

end:
    popl   %ebp
    ret
```